# set the source of multiple images

Tags: jquery

I have 4 img in one div tag. I m getting source of images from database using jquery ajax and want to set the source to img one by one..how can i do this...thanks

```
<div class="item " style="width:450px;">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span13">
                        <div class="thumbnail" style="margin-left:15px;">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span13">
                        <div class="thumbnail" style="margin-left:15px;">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span13">
                        <div class="thumbnail" style="margin-left:15px;">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span13">
                        <div class="thumbnail" style="margin-left:15px;">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
```

here is the code for retriving the source from database

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebServices/BannerImage.asmx/GetAllManufactureImage",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $.map(data.d, function (item) {
               // set the source to image
            });
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show the javascript code where you are retrieving the source of the images from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d, function(idx,item){
       $('img').eq(idx).attr('src',item);
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: I assumed that data.d is the image source.